# Dynamic Playlist exoplayer ConcatenatingMediaSource

Tags: android, exoplayer

I am trying to insert a media source in between the content once the playback has started.
Following is the code

```
 val userAgent = Util.getUserAgent(this, "Demo")
    val defaultMediaSource = DefaultDataSourceFactory(this, userAgent)
     progressiveMediaSource = ProgressiveMediaSource.Factory(defaultMediaSource)
    val hlsMediaSource = HlsMediaSource.Factory(defaultMediaSource)
     movieMediaSource =
        hlsMediaSource.createMediaSource(contentClipMediaItem())
      concatMediaSource = ConcatenatingMediaSource( getClippedMedia(0, 20))
    player.addMediaSource(concatMediaSource)
    player.prepare()
    player.playWhenReady = true
```

The content clip media item method

```
private fun contentClipMediaItem(): MediaItem {
    return MediaItem.Builder()
        .setUri(binding.txtStream.text.toString())
        .setMediaId("content")
        .build()
}
```

The `getClippedMedia` method

```
fun getClippedMedia(startPosition: Long, endPosition: Long): ClippingMediaSource {

    return ClippingMediaSource(movieMediaSource, startPosition*1000*1000, endPosition*1000*1000)
}
```

And on click of button am adding another clipping during playback

```
 binding.midRollBtn1.setOnClickListener {
        concatMediaSource.addMediaSource(getClippedMedia(20, 40))
    }
```

Over here only first clip is getting played